# Boost Log run-time optimization

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I am using Boost-Log and the global severity logger for my application's logging platform.
Profiling shows that the `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record` can take up to
25% of the total execution time.

I do have many log messages BUT I would not expect them to be so costly since **they are
lower severity and they are filtered**.

**Is there a way to make those messages not so costly in run-time?** (again: I expect to have a small overhead even when filtered and of course a larger when not-filrered).

Compile-time is relatively easy to "fix" this by creating some wrapper macros.

**UPDATED with sample working code:**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/empty_deleter.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

// severity levels
enum severity_level {INFO};

// Logging macro
#define LOG(level) BOOST_LOG_SEV(global_logger::get(), level)

// Initializing global boost::log logger
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<
    severity_level, std::string> global_logger_type;

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(global_logger, global_logger_type)
{
    return global_logger_type(boost::log::keywords::channel = "global_logger");
}

// Initialize terminal logger
void init_logger(int verbosity)
{
    namespace bl = boost::log;
    typedef bl::sinks::synchronous_sink<bl::sinks::text_ostream_backend>
      text_sink;

    boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, boost::empty_deleter()));

    sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);

    sink->set_formatter(bl::expressions::stream << bl::expressions::message);

    sink->set_filter(bl::expressions::attr<severity_level>("Severity")
                     < (severity_level) verbosity);

    bl::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    bl::add_common_attributes();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    init_logger(boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]));
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        std::sin(std::sin(17.2)); // dummy processing
        LOG(INFO) << "A message!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running with argument `0` does not print any log messages but it takes twice (!) the
time than commenting out the LOG message.

Comment: Show us some sample code.  A minimal working program if you can.

Comment: Seems that this 2x slowdown (when most messages were filtered) was present since it was first accepted as a Boost Library. http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2010/03/0256.php

Comment: you might want to assess an asynchronous logging library, such as [g2log](https://bitbucket.org/KjellKod/g2log) or at least [google-glog](https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/) which buffers writes

Answer (score 0):

Often, when logging, what is being logged has to be evaluated, and that evaluation happens before the actual decision whether to log or not is made.  For example:

```
log.debug("The current state of the system is: " + system.expensiveFunctionToGatherState());
```

We had a home grown logging system that added the current time to the log, which was a call to `gettimeofday()`.  Turned out 20% of the CPU consumption in the program was calls into `gettimeofday()` for log functions that never went anywhere.

Comment: I Boost's case, I am almost certain that no evaluation happens. As I show in the example, where a simple string is logged, execution time is increased significantly.

Comment: @DimitrisDakopoulos, I would imagine they are, as the output stream operator would be called with the individual arguments that are chained, I don't know how boost log is implemented, but even in the ignored case, it probably has to return something which will support the stream operator - which in turn will be called for all the values streamed in...

Answer (score 0):

One workaround (this is a marmite solution btw.) is to use a macro to wrap the logging, for example:

```
#define LOG_INFO(x) \
  if (<test if log level is INFO>) { \
    LOG(INFO) << x;  \
  }
```

Then:

```
LOG_INFO("Foo" << "Bar" << someExpensiveFunction());
```

You can be sure that the `someExpensiveFunction()` will only be executed at a level that supports `INFO`.

Heck, you could even go as far as compiling it out completely,

```
#ifndef _NINFO_
#define LOG_INFO(x) \
  if (<test if log level is INFO>) { \
    LOG(INFO) << x;  \
  }
#else
#define LOG_INFO(x)
#endif
```

Another advantage of this would be that you could change the logging implementation by modifying the macro rather than than changing all your code every where..